# I am trying to determine an array of given characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to determine the favorite drinks of an array of given 
characters (useful for party planning)

parameter: characterArray an array of dictionaries 
return: an array of favorite drinks

```
 {
 "name": "Nog",
 "rank": "Lieutenant junior grade",
 "information": "the first Ferengi to enter Starfleet",
 "favorite drink": "root beer",
 "quote": "Hear all, trust nothing."
 }
```

I don't even know where to start. Any hints?

---

```
- (NSArray *)arrayOfFavoriteDrinksForStarTrekCharacters:(NSArray *)charactersArray {



return @[];
}
```

Comment: Please give some data. It's just function!!

Comment: Hey @keyurbhalodiya! I added the array of dictionaries that was provided to me. Does that help?

Comment: @Keno You want array from "favorite drink" key?

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya yes! assuming he has a few drinks, I want to return all of them

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
return [charactersArray valueForKey: @"favorite drink"];
```

That would work if you have, say, an array of dictionaries.